# How to detect if a link already is in the user's bookmarks?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, bookmarks

Is it possible to determine from a Greasemonkey script if a link is already in the bookmarks or not? 
E. g. if I want to mark all links on the page which are bookmarked.

Also, how can I find the name of the folder where this bookmark is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Greasemonkey script cannot tell if a link is in the browser's/user's bookmarks because:

1. [Ordinary javascript is not allowed to know this for security reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25707364/331508)
2. Greasemonkey does not provide this capability and [Greasemonkey's controlling developers have consistently refused to add similar capabilities](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1316).

See, also, ["How can I detect visited and unvisited links on a page?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7291538/331508).

---

[Firefox add-ons *can* do this though](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Bookmarks#Checking_to_see_if_a_URI_is_bookmarked). So, if you were feeling frisky, you could either fork Greasemonkey and add this capability or you could write a helper add-on that could message your script.